# How can I convert a value type cast as an object to a string using XmlConvert?

Tags: c#, xml

I'm looking for something equivalent to the code below but for any value type without having to encode a switch statement for each data type.
The code below does not compile because XmlConvert.ToString() does not have an overload that accepts and object.

```
        int intValue = 10;
        object boxedValue = (object)intValue;
        string xmlValue = XmlConvert.ToString(boxedValue);
```

In other words, is there a better way than this:

```
public static string ToXmlString(Type type, object value) {

        switch(Type.GetTypeCode(type)) {
            case TypeCode.Int32:
                return XmlConvert.ToString((int) value);
            case TypeCode.DateTime:
                return XmlConvert.ToString((DateTime) value, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.Unspecified);
            case TypeCode.Boolean:
                return XmlConvert.ToString((bool) value);

            // TODO:  Add case for all other value types!

            default:
                return value.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

All value types are inherently serializable. So you just need to use an XMLSerializer. 
Something like this would do it (based on your method):

```
public static string ToXmlString(Type type, object value)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    System.Xml.XmlWriter writer = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(sb);
    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serial = 
        new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(type);
    serial.Serialize(writer, value);
}
```

Comment: The funny thing is if you use Reflector to trace into XmlSerializer.Serialize you eventually hit a method called SerializePrimitive which has a big switch statement that dispatches to methods that eventually call XmlConvert.ToString where they cast the object to the native type.

Comment: But is this a bad thing? All that's happening is that the switch is moved from your code into framework code.

Comment: The result of ToXmlString(typeof(boolean), true) is
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><boolean>true</boolean> 
which is not the exprected "true". The result has to be mapped again to make it work. I prefer the "hard" way as proposed by Darrel.

Comment: Sorry, how can this be voted up? its not working as other comments also has noted, it returns xml and not the expected xml value?

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use Reflector to look at then make a copy of System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.GetStringValue (it's internal unfortunatly)

Answer (score 1):

I had to do the opposite opposite conversion (string to type) as part of a serializer I wanted to write (avoiding the built in one, for Reasons).  I was doing the deserialize and this was the only post to talk about it, so I'm updating with my answer while it's still fresh.

The method I used was to use reflection to basically work out what I needed to do.  The variable type in the following example is the Type object of the type I'm converting to, E is an XmlNode whose contents I'll be converting and newVar is an instance of a template type T that I'll be returning.  This fragment does not assume any constraints on T (which is why there's no direct string assign/cast) and assumes objects/enums are handled differently (objects and enums break this):

```
MethodInfo convertMethod;

if( Type.GetTypeCode(type) != TypeCode.String )
    convertMethod = typeof(XmlConvert).GetMethod ( "To" + type.Name );
else
    convertMethod = E.InnerText.GetType().GetMethod("Clone");

if( convertMethod == null )
{
    //Error
}
else
{
    if( Type.GetTypeCode (type)!= TypeCode.String )
        newVar = (T)convertMethod.Invoke( null, new object[] { E.InnerText } );
    else
        newVar = (T)convertMethod.Invoke ( E.InnerText, new object[]{} );
}
```

(String needs to be handled as a special case as ToString() does something else completely different and breaks everything).

The other way around (as per the original post) would be something like (not tested, will update if I write the serialize function):

```
MethodInfo convertMethod;

if( Type.GetTypeCode(type) != TypeCode.String )
    convertMethod = typeof(XmlConvert).GetMethod ( "ToString", new Type[] {typeof(T)} );
else
    convertMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Clone");

if( convertMethod == null )
{
    //Error
}
else
{
    string str;
    if( Type.GetTypeCode (type)!= TypeCode.String )
        str = (string)convertMethod.Invoke( null, new object[] { Value } );
    else
        str = (string)convertMethod.Invoke ( Value, new object[]{} );
}
```

In this case, conversion is from T to string and Value contains a type T that we're converting from.  The difference is that we ask for ToString but specify the function with one parameter of type T.  This should be unique enough.

Answer (score 0):

Just to throw this out there, are you attempting to convert a business object into XML?

Perhaps you might want to look at XmlSerialization.  If you mark some attributes on your business object .Net will do all the fancy XML stuff for you :).

Also, is there any reason why you are boxing your value?  XmlConvert.ToString() has 19 overloads, many of which take primitives.

Comment: I appreciate the heads up, but I've been through XmlSerializer, DataContractSerializer hell.  I've even played with XamlWriter.  My values are boxed because I am accessing them through an Interface that  deals with many datatypes.